# How to receive a file over bluetooth on Fedora 24 using the cli?

Tags: fedora, xfce, bluetooth

This question may have already been asked but I just can't find how to make it work.

So far this is what I have found (and failed):

- Using obexpush (the command doesn't even exist, the closest match is obex_push)
- Using obexftpd fails with 'register to SDP server failed.' Waiting for connection. and nothing else happens, I can't receive files.
- obex_push also fails with sdptool add --channel=12 OPUSH (12 is the OPUSH channel on my cellphone, found using hcitool browse).

So far I can pair, connect and 'trust' my device using bluetoothctl and stream audio plus internet connection to my PC but that's about it. I can't seem to find a way to send a file from my cellphone to the PC. Is there any way to do this or at least a reference as to how all of this works?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I've managed to get it working, it was just an issue with bluez 5 and its lack of backwards compatibility with bluez 4. As fair as I could understand you first have to add an sdp listener, service or whatever, using: `sdptool add OPUSH` in order to let the PC listen for incoming *obex push* messages, bus since sdptool expects the bluez 4 api, it fails to create the service. I noticed this because `sdptool browse local` failed too, and doing some research I learned about the bluez 4/5 thing. This is the reason why `obex_push` and `obexftp` failed too. In the end, the solution was to start the daemon in compatibility mode, by adding the `--compat` parameter to the executable, or rather, in the systemd file (in my case):

```
vi /usr/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service
```

and under [Service]:

`ExecStart=/usr/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd` -> `ExecStart=/usr/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd --compat`

I actually created two separate service files, bluetooth.service with the default config and bluetooth-compat.service with the compat flag and made it the default:

```
]# systemctl disable bluetooth.service
]# systemctl enable bluetooth-compat.service
```

I started the daemon again and now sdptool works just fine and I have just transfered a couple of medium sized files (5 MB). Great.

Comment: Not worked in fedora 25